# Determining time it takes for two approaching cars to meet

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently having problem with this question.
"Solve the problem involving uniform motion:
One car starts from the point A and moving to the point B.
Another car starts at the same time from the point B
and moves to the point A along the same highway towards the first car.
Assign your numbers for the speed of each car (mph),
and assign your number for distance between A and B (ml).
Make an equation with x as a time of movement.
Solve an equation for x to find how long it will take for cars to meet (find x)."

I came up with this answer, I'm not sure if it's right.
Speed of car A: 35mph

Speed of car B: 25mph

Distance: 240 miles

Time = distance/rate

x = 240 miles / 60 mph

x = 4 hours

or maybe (?)

240 = 40x + 25x

240 = 60x

240/60 = x

4 = x

If it's wrong, can someone please tell me what I did wrong, and help me with that mistake. Thank you!

Btw, if I tagged my question under the wrong labels; please edit that for me also. :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that the points A and B are $240$ miles apart?

Comment: The first solution is nicer. Probably the second solution is the intended one.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing fine except for the typo where you have $40x$ instead of $35x$ but that is corrected in the next line.  In your first solution, you should have some words to explain where the $60$ mph comes from-it is the closing speed of the two cars.